# Invoking javascript to force a browser to return more than the first page on search

Tags: javascript

I use a forum which has a search feature, but it will only return the first page of search results (25 count). Someone gave me this piece of javascript which could be used to get a browser to return and access all of the pages of search results. I don't understand how that might work. I'm using Edge.

```
javascript:var frm = document.frmPage1; if (frm==null || frm.CtlPaging_selPage==null) alert(&quot;Not a TS search page&quot;); else { frm.CtlPaging_selPage.value = prompt(&quot;choose page&quot;,2); frm.submit(); }
```

[Tradestation user forum](https://community.tradestation.com/discussions/Main.aspx)
There are many things about this forum that are broken. It was designed for IE and there has been minimal updating. Users generally hate it.

Comment: You should name the site, or at least the forum engine and version, as the way to "hack it" heavily depends on the actual implementation.

Answer (score 0):

This code is designed to work with a specific pagination script that already has somewhere in its design an option that turns paginated results on or off.

What this code is doing is checking first to see if document.frmPage1.CtlPaging_selPage exists, because that is where this form stores the variable that defines if it will paginate or not.  If it finds this, it uses a prompt to set it to the value to "2" which tells the system to return unpaginated results, then it submits the form.

Most likely the forum either has a an input somewhere you are not seeing that allows you to turn off pagination, or the developer/admin who setup the forum is hiding this option on purpose, but did not actually delete it from his code.